# Display answer in a dialog pop up

Tags: android, json

I have a local json file that stores questions

```
("Questions ": [
  {
    "question": ".........",
    "answer1": ".......",
    "answer2": " ......",
    "answer3": ".......",
    "correctAnswer: "........"
  },
  {
    "question": ".........",
    "answer1": ".......",
    "answer2": " ......",
    "answer3": ".......",
    "correctAnswer: "........"
})
```

I created the xml layout that take the data and store it onto it. When a user selects submit answer, I want to be able to display a dialog box stating if answer selected was correct/incorrect along with the correct answer displayed(corrrectAnswer). How to do this?

//xml layout quiz

Question(TextView

Ans1
Ans2 (radioButtons)
Ans3

```
  Submit answer
       (Button)
```

Comment: You do know how to parse it right?

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE I was able to parse the json file but only able to display one question in my xml layout. This is also a problem that I am having along with creating a pop up dialog box for the correct answer.

Comment: Why are you unable to display 2 questions? and for the pop up box Will Evers answer is perfect for showing the dialog box. Pls check his answer and also let me know why you couldn't display 2 questions :)

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setTitle("Title Text").
            .setMessage(*String comprised of your desired notification content*)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //for clicking OK

                }
            })

            .show();

    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```